# Filtering hierarchies in MDX WITH clause

Tags: ssas, mdx, olap

By using the answer of [MDX on multiple hierarchical dimensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6268451/mdx-on-multiple-hierarchical-dimensions/6274438) I have the following MDX query:

```
with
member L1Y1 as ([Dim Location].[Hierarchy].[Center].&[1],
        [Dim Date].[Calendar Date].[Year].&[2010],
        [Measures].[x])                 
select ([Dim Attribute].[Parent Code].&[10000]) on 0, 
       ({L1Y1}) on 1
from DS
```

Now the problem is how to filter the L1Y1 based on its children. For example suppose we want to filter it so that only season 2 and month 7 included in the query. The following query output is the same as above and the `where` clause has no effect:

```
with
member L1Y1 as ([Dim Location].[Hierarchy].[Center].&[1],
        [Dim Date].[Calendar Date].[Year].&[2010],
        [Measures].[x])                 
select ([Dim Attribute].[Parent Code].&[10000]) on 0, 
       ({L1Y1}) on 1
from DS
where [Dim Date].[Calendar Date].[Season].&[2] and 
      [Dim Date].[Calendar Date].[Month].&[7]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
with
member L1Y1 as ([Dim Location].[Hierarchy].[Center].&[1],
        [Dim Date].[Calendar Date].[Year].&[2010],
        [Measures].[x])
member S2 as ([Dim Location].[Hierarchy].[Center].&[1],
        [Dim Date].[Calendar Date].[Season].&[2],
        [Measures].[x])
member M7 as ([Dim Location].[Hierarchy].[Center].&[1],
        [Dim Date].[Calendar Date].[Month].&[7],
        [Measures].[x])     
select ([Dim Attribute].[Parent Code].&[10000]) on 0, 
       (L1Y1, S2, M7) on 1
from DS
```

I understand it is a somewhat more laborous approach, but you would get the result. If you otherwise want to get a single value only you can try keeping only the M7 measure.

Comment: Thanks. This was not exactly what I was looking for, but guided me a lot.

Comment: And would you please answer this one too? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6308165/merging-two-tuples-in-the-same-hierarchy-into-one-in-mdx-with-set-command

Answer (score 2):

Unless you removed the attributes you should have multiple hierarchies available in your time dimension. Can you try this :

```
with
member L1Y1 as ([Dim Location].[Hierarchy].[Center].&[1],
    [Dim Date].[Calendar Date].[Year].&[2010],
    [Measures].[x])                 
select ([Dim Attribute].[Parent Code].&[10000]) on 0, 
   ({L1Y1}) on 1
from DS
where [Dim Date].[Season].&[2] and [Dim Date].[Month].&[7]
```

Note, as we are *not* using the hierarchy [Calendar Date] time member is not overwritten but filtered.

Comment: But it does not work when dimensions of where clause are not the same.

Comment: In your example all are hierarchies of [Dim Date], aren't they?.. if no you're right

Comment: From SSAS view point(!) [Dim Date].[Season] and [Dim Data].[Month] are different hierarchies of [Dim Data] dimension.

Comment: if they are hierarchies of the same dimension, it should work, isn't it ?

Comment: -> where ([Dim Date].[Season].&[2],[Dim Date].[Month].&[7])

Comment: If we put them in parentheses as a tuple, it would work. But the problem is including both of second season and seventh month in query output, not the intersection of them.

Comment: you're making my life hard :-), you can use a set in the filter instead of a single tuple: where { ([Dim Date].[Season].&[2],[Dim Date].[Month].[All Member]) + ([Dim Date].[Season].[All Member],[Dim Date].[Month].&[7]) }